# How to create JPA multiple count in criteria builder?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am creating two counts for failed mails and total mails using JPA criteria builder. I am not getting how to take two counts in JPA. These two methods I tried but I'm getting some error.

```java
//1st way
Root<sourceTracking> u = cq.from(sourceTracking.class);
Expression<sourceTracking> status=u.get("delivery_status");
List<sourceTracking> columns=new ArrayList<sourceTracking>();
columns.add((sourceTracking) u.get("mail_server"));
columns.add((sourceTracking) cb.count(cb.selectCase().when(cb.equal(status, "deferred"), 1L)));
columns.add((sourceTracking) cb.count(u));
cq.multiselect(columns);
//here multiselect getting error

//2nd way
cq.multiselect(u.<String>get("mail_server"),cb.sum(cb.selectCase()
.when(cb.equal(u.<String>get("delivery_status"), "deferred"),1)
.otherwise(0)),cb.count(u)).groupBy(u.<String>get("mail_server"));
//here sum getting error
```